# message template are not working in kore.ai

Tags: chatbot

I want to display list to the user with kore.ai, currently, I am using telegram but the template is not working it is just showing the code.

```
var message={
"type": "template",
"payload":
{
"template_type": "button",
"text": "What do you want to do next?",
"buttons":
[{
"type": "web_url",
"title": "Show Website",
"url": "https://petersapparel.parseapp.com"
},
{
"type": "postback",
 "title": "Start Chatting",
"payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
}
]
}
}
print(JSON.stringify(message));
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some templates are channel specific which means not every end channel supports each and every templates . Please try with different channels such as Web or Facebook messenger, your template will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that the template  structure is supported by the channel. 
The channels usually have the template structures defined on their technical documentation.
Please select the appropriate channel on the bot builder and then use the template structure as they have defined.

Comment: Is there anything i have to enable like some SDK. Because it also not even showing in the kore.ai test bot.

Comment: I am not sure, I under the question right.. Are you following https://community.kore.ai  Please check if you could find an answer or post a topic.